# AutoDesk BIM 360 CheckPermission API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

We are trying to use the CheckPermission command in the BIM 360 Forge API. The [documentation](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/CheckPermission/) for allowed BIM 360 permissions includes 'edit', but an error is returned that it is invalid.

The returned list of allowed values is ["read","view","download","collaborate","write","create","upload","updateMetaData","delete","admin","share"] but when you try to use 'write' an error is returned.

I am trying to check the permission on both folders and items. How can I tell if a user has write/edit permission? Also which permission is used to determine if a user can delete a folder/item?

Comment: The permission is mainly based on folder. It corresponds to the UI setting  http://help.autodesk.com/view/BIM360D/ENU/?guid=GUID-2643FEEF-B48A-45A1-B354-797DAD628C37 . So, if a user can edit a folder, then he has edit permission on the items/folder. and can also delete the item/folder

Comment: Yes, but how do I tell if the user has edit permission? I receive an error that 'edit' and 'write' aren't valid options

Comment: 'write' applies with BIM360 Team, Fusion Team, A360 Personal Term, while 'edit' applies with BIM 360 Docs. It looks there is issue with 'edit' when I tested. Please bear with me checking with engineer team

Comment: I've been experimenting and its seems like the updateMetaData priv is equivalent to edit.

Comment: Our engineer team also confirmed the corresponding permissions with `edit` in UI are 'create' and 'updateMetaData' in API. The help document is misleading. Our apology for this! We will update the document soon.

Comment: Thank you, and please talk with them about changing the list of valid enums that are returned in the error response.